# ActiveAdmin register_page doesn't work in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activeadmin

The app crash when I add the next code (from the Active Admin web page):

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Calendar" do
  content do
    para "Hello World"
  end
end
```

If I execute the same code at heroku console, it works well. But the web app can't get up with this code. In the logs only shows that the app crash with timeout.

The Dashboard page uses the old `ActiveAdmin::Dashboards.build`, and I can't get work with `ActiveAdmin.register_page`for the same reason.

I've Active Admin 0.5.1 and Rails 3.2.11

Comment: Try to update to 0.6.6 or 1.0.0

Comment: I can't update to 1.0.0, I've to update rails in a big project

Comment: As @TimoSchilling suggested, try upgrading to 0.6. It will require minimal updating of your existing code.  `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin', branch: '0-6-stable'`

Comment: You don't need to use `0.6.6`, from Github, you can use the gem

Comment: And you don't need to update Rails, to use AA 1.0.0, AA 1.0.0 supports Rails 3.2

Comment: I need Rails 3.2.13 to update Active Admin, and I've 3.2.11